# How to impose a required textbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, required

I have a problem with my chat.
Indeed, I have a text input with the required value.
When I click on Send, it returns empty instead of stopped sending...
Can you help me please ?

```
<script>
    $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        $.post("chat-post.php", {
            text: clientmsg
        }); 

$("#usermsg").attr('required', true);

        loadLog;
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The very first step is to look at the error console and looking whether there's any errors. What is `loadLog`, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could validate the input string like this `if(clientmsg.trim())` .Better add the `required=true` in your html code

```
 <input type='text' required="true">
```

And use with `trim()` they will remove the unwanted space from string

```
<script>
    $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
        var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
        if(clientmsg.trim()){
        $.post("chat-post.php", {
            text: clientmsg
        }); 
        loadLog;
        }
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to add a condition before sending post request if the value of that message input is empty. Please check below :

```
    <script>
        $("#submitmsg").click(function() {
            var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();

// This is the additional condition
            if(clientmsg != '' || clientmsg != null){

                $.post("chat-post.php", {
                    text: clientmsg
                }); 
            }
            else{
                alert('Please enter the message!');
            }

    $("#usermsg").attr('required', true);

            loadLog;
            return false;
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Patric, I have added the explaination in there. :)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the required attribute to work, you need to have the input inside a form.

```
<form>
  <input required type="text" />
</form>
```

I think there is simply no need to set the required attribute every time you click the button. You only need to do it once, so why not simply add the required attribute in the html?

Even if you don't want to add it in the HTML, just add it once.

```
<script>
  $("#usermsg").attr('required', true); // Add the attribute required to the input

  // Do the AJAX function after you submit the form.
  // Before submitting, it will have to be validated, so you don't even have to validate it in JS. Just native HTML5
      $("form").submit(function() {
        // do the rest here
      }
    </script>
```